# Oracle Certified Professional, Java SE Programmer

Tags: java, oracle

I have been a Java programmer for nearly twelve years. Also, I hold the previous Java 1.4 programmer certification from Sun (SCJP). I am considering updating my certification.

Can anyone confirm that if you have a previous SCJP certification, then you only have to take one exam? I am just curious how they know that you previously passed a previous exam from Sun.

Finally, can anyone recommend any study resources for the exam?

Thank you!

Comment: You might like to review [this](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/OCAJP7andOCPJP7vsOCJP6).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Java Certification.

Comment: Hi Jimmy. his is an interesting question. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow works best for questions that are specific, technical questions related directly to programming problems. This is a question about your certification - and unfortunately doesn't fit the usual profile for Stack Overflow questions. This is why it was voted to be closed and it will not be reopened for that reason. This just isn't the right place to ask it. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already you had SCJP 1.4, So you can go for OCPJP 7 Upgrade Certification 1Z0-805. I refer you to the following page, it will give you an idea about Upgrade certification.

http://www.epractizelabs.com/oracle/java-certifications/what-is-ocpjp-7-upgrade.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes .. The Professional programmer exam (next level after associate J2SE) will help you `100%` in a raise or better future position. And I say this based on experience.

Answer (score 1):

I am a SCJP 1.4 just like you (got mine in 2003/4 - I can't remember) and I am studying to get my upgrade (1Z0-805), so I am in the same page of you.

When I've got my SCJP, It was helpful for me because I was learning the language.

Well, since then, many things have changed. Java changed a lot and it will change even more and even faster. Oracle certainly has found its path to make money on us, in the same way SAP consultants pay even more to get certified.

So, yes, I think this new certification will be good for you, if your idea (as it's my idea too) is to keep working with Java for some more years, or even decades.

To study, I recommend Ganesh and Sharma's book. Does not cover 100%, of course, but it's pretty useful.